# Como posso fazer de forma correta o foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql

Bom dia, como posso fazer de forma correta este foreach, pois eu não estou conseguindo fazer UPDATE nas tabelas *nomedependente, cpfdependente, datanascimentodependente, planodependente, acomodacaodependente, grauparentescodependente e valordependente*.

## Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="process_form.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="<?php echo ($_GET["m"] == "update") ? "update_old" : "add_new"; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="old_pic" value="<?php echo $results[0]["profile_pic"] ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo intval($results[0]["id"]); ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="pagenum" value="<?php echo $_GET["pagenum"]; ?>" >

    <div class="box-body">

      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <b>Número do Contrato:</b>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numerocontrato" value="<?php echo $results[0]["numerocontrato"] ?>" name="numerocontrato" placeholder="N.  Contrato">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <label for="campo1">Usuário do plano</label>
          <input name="id_cpf_cnpj" autocomplete="off" type="radio" onClick="habilitaCamposUsuario('usuario1')" value="1" checked/>
          <label for="radio2">Responsável Financeiro</label>
          <input name="id_cpf_cnpj" type="radio" value="2"  onClick="habilitaCamposUsuario('usuario2')"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <b>Nome responsável:</b>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_completo" value="<?php echo $results[0]["nome_completo"] ?>" name="nome_completo" placeholder="Nome Completo">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2" id="usuarioPlano" style="display: block;">
          <b>Valor da Adesão:</b>
          <input type="text" id="txt1" name="adesao" class="form-control calcular" value="<?php echo $results[0]["adesao"] ?>" placeholder="R$" onkeypress="mascara(this,mreais)" onkeyup="calcular()">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2" id="usuarioFinanceiro" style="display: none;">
          <b>Valor da Adesão:</b>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor_adesao" name="valor_adesao" disabled="" placeholder="Usuário Financeiro">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <b>Valor Total:</b>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="result" value="<?php echo $results[0]["total"] ?>" readonly>
        </div>


      </div>


      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <label for="campo1">CPF</label>
          <input name="cpfoucnpj" type="radio" value="1" onClick="habilitaCamposUsuarioCPFouCNPJ('cpfUsuario')" checked />
          <label for="radio2">CNPJ</label>
          <input name="cpfoucnpj" type="radio" value="2" onClick="habilitaCamposUsuarioCPFouCNPJ('cpfUsuario2')"/>
        </div>


  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <b>CPF ou CNPJ:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["cpfoucnpjnumero"] ?>" name="cpfoucnpjnumero" onkeydown="javascript:return aplica_mascara_cpfcnpj(this,18,event)" onkeyup="javascript:return aplica_mascara_cpfcnpj(this,18,event)" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ">
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <b>Data de Nascimento:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["data_nascimento"] ?>" id="data_nascimento" onkeypress="mascara(this,mdata)" name="data_nascimento" onblur="calculaIdade()" placeholder="__/__/____" />

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <h4 style="color: red" id="idade"></h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h4 style="color: black">anos de idade.</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <b>E-mail:</b>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["email"] ?>" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <b>CEP (Somente números):</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["cep"] ?>" name="cep" id="cep" maxlength="9" OnKeyPress="formatar('#####-###', this)" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <b>Rua:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["rua"] ?>" name="rua" id="rua" size="45" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <b>Número:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["numero"] ?>" name="numero" id="numero" size="5" />

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <b>Bairro:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["bairro"] ?>" name="bairro" id="bairro" size="25" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <b>Cidade:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["cidade"] ?>" name="cidade" id="cidade" size="25" />
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <b>Estado:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["estado"] ?>" name="estado" id="estado" value="<?php echo $results[0]["estado"] ?>" size="2" />
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <b>Vendedor:</b>
    <select id="id_vendedor" class="form-control" name="id_vendedor">
      <option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_vendedor']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["nome_vendedor"]; ?></option>
      <?php
      $consulta = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM vendedor ORDER BY nome_vendedor DESC");
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $linha['id'] . '">' . $linha['nome_vendedor'] . '</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <b>Forma de Pagamento:</b>
    <select id="id_forma_pagamento" class="form-control" name="id_forma_pagamento">
      <option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_forma_pagamento']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["forma_pagamento"]; ?></option>
      <?php
      $consulta = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM forma_pagamento ORDER BY forma_pagamento ASC");
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $linha['id'] . '">' . $linha['forma_pagamento'] . '</option>';
      }          
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <b>Qual forma?</b>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_forma" name="id_forma">
      <option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_forma']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["nome_forma"]; ?></option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>Sexo:</b>
    <select id="id_sexo" class="form-control" name="id_sexo">
      <option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_sexo']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["sexo"]; ?></option>
      <?php
      $consulta = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM sexo ORDER BY sexo ASC");
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="' . $linha['id'] . '">' . $linha['sexo'] . '</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>Data de Vencimento:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["data_vencimento"] ?>" id="data_vencimento" name="data_vencimento" onkeypress="mascara(this,mdata)" placeholder="__/__/____">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>Revenda:</b>
    <select id="id_revenda" class="form-control" name="id_revenda">
      <option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_revenda']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["nome_revenda"]; ?></option>
      <?php
      $consulta = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM revenda ORDER BY nome_revenda ASC");
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="' . $linha['id'] . '">' . $linha['nome_revenda'] . '</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="form-group">

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>Plano:</b>
    <select id="id_plano" class="form-control" name="id_plano">
      <option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_plano']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["nome_plano"]; ?></option>
      <?php
      $consulta = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM plano ORDER BY nome_plano ASC");
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="' . $linha['id'] . '">' . $linha['nome_plano'] . '</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>Acomodação:</b>
    <select id="id_acomodacao" class="form-control" name="id_acomodacao">
      <option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_acomodacao']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["acomodacao"]; ?></option>
      <?php
      $consulta = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM acomodacao ORDER BY acomodacao ASC");
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="' . $linha['id'] . '">' . $linha['acomodacao'] . '</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>Telefone:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["telefone"] ?>" id="telefone" placeholder="( ) _____-____" name="telefone" onkeyup="mascara( this, mtel );" maxlength="15">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>Celular:</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $results[0]["celular"] ?>" name="celular" placeholder="( ) _____-____" onkeyup="mascara( this, mtel );" maxlength="15" />
  </div>
</div>

      <!-- DEPENDENTES -->

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Dependentes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;" >

              <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left"style="padding-left: 0;"  >
                <span class="pull-left">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php if ($results > 0) { ?>
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered ">
                  <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Nome do Dependente</th>
                    <th>CPF</th>
                    <th>Data de Nascimento</th>
                    <th>Plano </th>
                    <th>Acomodação </th>
                    <th>Grau Parentesco </th>
                    <th>Valor do Dependente </th>
                  </tr>
                  **<?php foreach ($results as $res) { ?>**
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $res["nomedependente"]; ?>" name="nomedependente"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $res["cpfdependente"]; ?>" name="cpfdependente"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $res["datanascimentodependente"]; ?>" name="datanascimentodependente"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $res["planodependente"]; ?>" name="planodependente"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $res["acomodacaodependente"]; ?>" name="acomodacaodependente"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $res["grauparentescodependente"]; ?>" name="grauparentescodependente"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" onkeypress="mascara(this,mreais)" onkeyup="calcular()" class="form-control calcular" value="<?php echo $res["valordependente"]; ?>" name="valordependente"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
             </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                  <div class="well well-lg"><b>Nenhum dependente encontrado.</b></div>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
              </div>

        <td colspan="6" style="text-align: left;">
           <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
        </td>
  </tfoot>
</table>

            </fieldset>
          </form>
```

## process_form.php

```
      <?php

  require './config.php';
  $mode = $_REQUEST["mode"];
  if ($mode == "add_new" ) {

    $numerocontrato = trim($_POST['numerocontrato']);
    $id_cpf_cnpj = trim($_POST['id_cpf_cnpj']);
    $nome_completo = trim($_POST['nome_completo']);
    $adesao = trim($_POST['adesao']);
    $cpfoucnpj = trim($_POST['cpfoucnpj']);
    $cpfoucnpjnumero = trim($_POST['cpfoucnpjnumero']);
    $data_nascimento = trim($_POST['data_nascimento']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $cep = trim($_POST['cep']);
    $rua = trim($_POST['rua']);
    $numero = trim($_POST['numero']);
    $bairro = trim($_POST['bairro']);
    $cidade = trim($_POST['cidade']);
    $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
    $id_vendedor = trim($_POST['id_vendedor']);
    $id_forma_pagamento = trim($_POST['id_forma_pagamento']);
    $id_forma = trim($_POST['id_forma']);
    $id_sexo = trim($_POST['id_sexo']);
    $data_vencimento = trim($_POST['data_vencimento']);
    $id_revenda = trim($_POST['id_revenda']);
    $id_plano = trim($_POST['id_plano']);
    $id_acomodacao = trim($_POST['id_acomodacao']);
    $telefone = trim($_POST['telefone']);
    $celular = trim($_POST['celular']);
    $total = trim($_POST['total']);
    $nomedependente = trim($_POST['nomedependente']);
    $cpfdependente = trim($_POST['cpfdependente']);
    $datanascimentodependente = trim($_POST['datanascimentodependente']);
    $planodependente = trim($_POST['planodependente']);
    $acomodacaodependente = trim($_POST['acomodacaodependente']);
    $grauparentescodependente = trim($_POST['grauparentescodependente']);
    $valordependente = trim($_POST['valordependente']);
    $error = FALSE;

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"])) {
      $filename = time() . '_' . $_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"];
      $filepath = 'profile_pics/' . $filename;
      if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)) {
        $error = TRUE;
      }
    }

    if (!$error) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_contacts` (`numerocontrato`, `middle_name`, `nome_completo`, `estado`, `contact_no1`, `contact_no2`, `email_address`, `profile_pic`) VALUES "
              . "( :numerocontrato, :nome_completo, :email, :estado, :contact1, :contact2, :email, :pic)";

      try {
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

        // bind the values
        $stmt->bindValue(":numerocontrato", $numerocontrato);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_cpf_cnpj", $id_cpf_cnpj);
        $stmt->bindValue(":nome_completo", $nome_completo);
        $stmt->bindValue(":adesao", $adesao);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cpfoucnpj", $cpfoucnpj);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cpfoucnpjnumero", $cpfoucnpjnumero);
        $stmt->bindValue(":data_nascimento", $data_nascimento);
        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cep", $cep);
        $stmt->bindValue(":rua", $rua);
        $stmt->bindValue(":numero", $numero);
        $stmt->bindValue(":bairro", $bairro);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cidade", $cidade);
        $stmt->bindValue(":estado", $estado);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_vendedor", $id_vendedor);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_forma_pagamento", $id_forma_pagamento);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_forma", $id_forma);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_sexo", $id_sexo);
        $stmt->bindValue(":data_vencimento", $data_vencimento);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_revenda", $id_revenda);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_plano", $id_plano);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_acomodacao", $id_acomodacao);
        $stmt->bindValue(":telefone", $telefone);
        $stmt->bindValue(":celular", $celular);
        $stmt->bindValue(":total", $total);
        $stmt->bindValue(":nomedependente", $nomedependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cpfdependente", $cpfdependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":datanascimentodependente", $datanascimentodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":planodependente", $planodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":acomodacaodependente", $acomodacaodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":grauparentescodependente", $grauparentescodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":valordependente", $valordependente);

        // execute Query
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($result > 0) {
          $_SESSION["errorType"] = "success";
          $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Contact added successfully.";
        } else {
          $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
          $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Failed to add contact.";
        }
      } catch (Exception $ex) {

        $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
      }
    } else {
      $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
      $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "failed to upload image.";
    }
    header("location:usuarios.php");
  } elseif ( $mode == "update_old" ) {

    $numerocontrato = trim($_POST['numerocontrato']);
    $id_cpf_cnpj = trim($_POST['id_cpf_cnpj']);
    $nome_completo = trim($_POST['nome_completo']);
    $adesao = trim($_POST['adesao']);
    $cpfoucnpj = trim($_POST['cpfoucnpj']);
    $cpfoucnpjnumero = trim($_POST['cpfoucnpjnumero']);
    $data_nascimento = trim($_POST['data_nascimento']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $cep = trim($_POST['cep']);
    $rua = trim($_POST['rua']);
    $numero = trim($_POST['numero']);
    $bairro = trim($_POST['bairro']);
    $cidade = trim($_POST['cidade']);
    $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
    $id_vendedor = trim($_POST['id_vendedor']);
    $id_forma_pagamento = trim($_POST['id_forma_pagamento']);
    $id_forma = trim($_POST['id_forma']);
    $id_sexo = trim($_POST['id_sexo']);
    $data_vencimento = trim($_POST['data_vencimento']);
    $id_revenda = trim($_POST['id_revenda']);
    $id_plano = trim($_POST['id_plano']);
    $id_acomodacao = trim($_POST['id_acomodacao']);
    $telefone = trim($_POST['telefone']);
    $celular = trim($_POST['celular']);
    $total = trim($_POST['total']);
    $nomedependente = trim($_POST['nomedependente']);
    $cpfdependente = trim($_POST['cpfdependente']);
    $datanascimentodependente = trim($_POST['datanascimentodependente']);
    $planodependente = trim($_POST['planodependente']);
    $acomodacaodependente = trim($_POST['acomodacaodependente']);
    $grauparentescodependente = trim($_POST['grauparentescodependente']);
    $valordependente = trim($_POST['valordependente']);
    $id = trim($_POST['numerocontrato']);
    $error = FALSE;

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"])) {
      $filename = time() . '_' . $_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"];
      $filepath = 'profile_pics/' . $filename;
      if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)) {
        $error = TRUE;
      }
    } else {
       $filename = $_POST['old_pic'];
    }

    if (!$error) {
      $sql = "UPDATE `cadastro_clientes` SET
                      `numerocontrato` = :numerocontrato,
                      `id_cpf_cnpj` = :id_cpf_cnpj,
                      `nome_completo` = :nome_completo,
                      `adesao` = :adesao,
                      `cpfoucnpj` = :cpfoucnpj,
                      `cpfoucnpjnumero` = :cpfoucnpjnumero,
                      `data_nascimento` = :data_nascimento,
                      `email` = :email,
                      `cep` = :cep,
                      `rua` = :rua,
                      `numero` = :numero,
                      `bairro` = :bairro,
                      `cidade` = :cidade,
                      `estado` = :estado,
                      `id_vendedor` = :id_vendedor,
                      `id_forma_pagamento` = :id_forma_pagamento,
                      `id_forma` = :id_forma,
                      `id_sexo` = :id_sexo,
                      `data_vencimento` = :data_vencimento,
                      `id_revenda` = :id_revenda,
                      `id_plano` = :id_plano,
                      `id_acomodacao` = :id_acomodacao,
                      `telefone` = :telefone,
                      `celular` = :celular,
                      `total` = :total,
                      `nomedependente` = :nomedependente,
                      `cpfdependente` = :cpfdependente,
                      `datanascimentodependente` = :datanascimentodependente,
                      `planodependente` = :planodependente,
                      `acomodacaodependente` = :acomodacaodependente,
                      `grauparentescodependente` = :grauparentescodependente,
                      `valordependente` = :valordependente

                       " . "WHERE numerocontrato = :numerocontrato ";

      try {
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

        // bind the values
        $stmt->bindValue(":numerocontrato", $numerocontrato);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_cpf_cnpj", $id_cpf_cnpj);
        $stmt->bindValue(":nome_completo", $nome_completo);
        $stmt->bindValue(":adesao", $adesao);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cpfoucnpj", $cpfoucnpj);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cpfoucnpjnumero", $cpfoucnpjnumero);
        $stmt->bindValue(":data_nascimento", $data_nascimento);
        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cep", $cep);
        $stmt->bindValue(":rua", $rua);
        $stmt->bindValue(":numero", $numero);
        $stmt->bindValue(":bairro", $bairro);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cidade", $cidade);
        $stmt->bindValue(":estado", $estado);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_vendedor", $id_vendedor);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_forma_pagamento", $id_forma_pagamento);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_forma", $id_forma);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_sexo", $id_sexo);
        $stmt->bindValue(":data_vencimento", $data_vencimento);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_revenda", $id_revenda);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_plano", $id_plano);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_acomodacao", $id_acomodacao);
        $stmt->bindValue(":telefone", $telefone);
        $stmt->bindValue(":celular", $celular);
        $stmt->bindValue(":total", $total);
        $stmt->bindValue(":nomedependente", $nomedependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cpfdependente", $cpfdependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":datanascimentodependente", $datanascimentodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":planodependente", $planodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":acomodacaodependente", $acomodacaodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":grauparentescodependente", $grauparentescodependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":valordependente", $valordependente);
        $stmt->bindValue(":numerocontrato", $id);

        // execute Query
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($result > 0) {
          $_SESSION["errorType"] = "success";
          $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Usuário atualizado com sucesso.";
        } else {
          $_SESSION["errorType"] = "info";
          $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Nenhuma alteração feita.";
        }
      } catch (Exception $ex) {

        $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
      }
    } else {
      $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
      $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Failed to upload image.";
    }

    // Aqui atualiza
    header("location:usuarios.php?pagenum=".$_POST['pagenum']);
  } elseif ( $mode == "delete" ) {
     $cid = intval($_GET['id']);

     $sql = "DELETE FROM `cadastro_clientes` WHERE id = :id";
     try {

        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id", $cid);

         $stmt->execute();
         $res = $stmt->rowCount();
         if ($res > 0) {
          $_SESSION["errorType"] = "success";
          $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Usuário excluído.";
        } else {
          $_SESSION["errorType"] = "info";
          $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Falha ao deletar contato.";
        }

     } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
     }

     header("location:usuarios.php?pagenum=".$_GET['pagenum']);
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: O que contem na variável `results`? É um number ou um array?

Comment: Array @RafaelMafra

Comment: Olá, Pode dar um exemplo do constragimento, não consegui perceber. O que dá o print_r($results)? O constragimento é no foreach ou é no momento da gravação? Verifico que os inputs não têm nomes dinamicos que origina erros

Comment: Não tem como colocar o print_r($results) aqui @TiagoGomes, tem como abrir um chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

não localizei nenhum foreach no codigo q mostro, mais segundo o http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

um foreach seria assim, o primeiro exemplo é dado o valor do índice do array para a variável $key.

e o segundo exemplo é separado o valor do array em duas variáveis, uma para a chave e outra para o valor, ficando acessíveis por essa variáveis durante a execucao do foreach.

Obs: as variaveis nao existem fora do foreach.

```
$dia = array('25' => 'Domingo','26' => 'Segunda','27' => 'Terça','28' => 'Quarta');

foreach ($dia as $key){
    echo 'Hoje é dia '.$key;
}

foreach ($dia as $key => $value){
    echo 'Hoje é dia '. $key. ' que caiu no '.$value;
}
```